# android how can I enable caps lock key programmatically?

Tags: android

How can I enable the caps lock key programmatically ?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add following to your edittext in xml file.

```
android:capitalize="characters
```

Comment: SO says that I have to wait for 6min to do that :(

Answer (score 0):

or you can send an event to your editText that left shift has been pressed every time you want to do this from code.

Comment: i am stuck on same problem Here is the question i posted     http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794848/turn-on-off-caps-lock-and-shift-key-programatically-on-android   . your answer seems you have very good understanding of this issue , but need more details regarding this.