# Turn on/off caps lock and shift key programatically on android

Tags: android, keyboard

I am developing an android application (keyboard driver) in which first I am connecting Bluetooth keyboard  with android device , after successful connection in my Inputmethod service I am receiving key presses and send it to currently open editor. The problem is that I am unable to figure out how to turn on/off caps lock and shift key functionality in android.

Any help !!

This is the  broadcast receiver which is receiving keys from Bluetooth keyboard

```
private BroadcastReceiver key3Receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        int key = Integer.parseInt(intent
                .getStringExtra(BluezService.COLONY_KEYPRESS_KEY));
        int action = intent.getIntExtra(BluezService.EVENT_KEYPRESS_ACTION,
                KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN);
        Log.d("++++ key recieved   ", Integer.toString(key));

        InputConnection ic = getCurrentInputConnection();
        long eventTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();

        // ********* Hacks
        if(key==8)
        {
            key=127;
        }


        if (key < 130) {                
            ic.sendKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(eventTime, eventTime, action,COLONYKEYCODE[key],
                    0, COLONYKEYCODE[key], 0, 0, KeyEvent.FLAG_SOFT_KEYBOARD));
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: Are you showing the Android soft Key board on the Screen while the user types something on the hardware keyboard?

Comment: no i am not showing soft keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

In your EditText (or wherever appropriate) use the attribute:

```
android:inputType="textCapCharacters"
```

to capitalize all letters by default.  Read [inputType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#inputType) for its other features.

Comment: This will not work if combined with `textPassword`, like this:
`android:inputType="textPassword| textCapCharacters"`, Do you know a way to combine password with caps letters?